# Cloudflare subdomain not working

Tags: subdomain, cloudflare

I never used CloudFlare or any service like this and I'm having some trouble.

I added a domain: http://alurabeautyshop.com and its working perfect.

Then I created 3 CNAME entries in the DNS Settings. 
They are 'images1', 'images2' and 'images3'. 
They will serve all my images and this is what I want to be cloudflared.

All this CNAME entries point to alurabeautyshop.com.

But when I access images1.alurabeautyshop.com the main site was not shown.

after this I noted that www.alurabeautyshop.com stopped working too.

I tried activating and deactivating the "grey cloud" (as described in another question) in all my new subdomains and my main www subdomain too, and waited about two hours after any changes, but nothing happened.

whats wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare is working well, you must configure the subdomains on your server, which I suppose can be done from here:

https://www.alurabeautyshop.com:8443/login_up.php3